# cAdvisor on my Mac won't get detailed info about containers. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: prometheus, cadvisor

First time user of cAdvisor here - I'm trying to set up a monitoring stack to get metrics on containers running a series of Python Flask apps. This is all on an M2 Mac, with intent to eventually deploy alongside my app to a Linux host with hopefully zero to minimal edits required to development configuration.

Here's my `docker compose` for cAdvisor with Prometheus, PromTail, Loki, and Grafana:

```yaml
version: '3'

networks:
  monitoring:

services:
  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor:v0.47.2
    platform: linux/aarch64 # Necessary for running on macOS, all other archs return more errors
    privileged: true
    container_name: cadvisor
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /etc/machine-id:/etc/machine-id:ro
      - /var/lib/dbus/machine-id:/var/lib/dbus/machine-id:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /sys:/sys:ro
      - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
      - /dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro
    networks:
      - monitoring

  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:2.4.0
    container_name: promtail
    volumes:
      - /var/log:/var/log
      - ./config/promtail:/etc/promtail
    command: --config.file=/etc/promtail/promtail-config.yml
    networks:
      - monitoring

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus-data:/prometheus
      - ./config/prometheus:/config
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    command: --config.file=/config/prometheus.yml
    networks:
      - monitoring
    depends_on:
      - cadvisor
  
  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:latest
    container_name: loki
    volumes:
      - ./config/loki:/etc/loki
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    command: --config.file=/etc/loki/loki-config.yml
    networks:
      - monitoring
    depends_on:
      - promtail

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./config/grafana:/var/lib/grafana
    networks:
      - monitoring
    depends_on:
      - loki
      - prometheus
```

And in case it's relevant, here's my prometheus config:

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']
        labels:
          alias: 'prometheus'

  - job_name: 'cadvisor'
    scrape_interval: 10s 
    metrics_path: '/metrics'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['cadvisor:8080']
        labels:
          group: 'cadvisor'
          alias: 'cadvisor'
```

The issue: I'm not getting detailed information about my containers to be able to filter them in Prometheus/Grafana.

Here's what I see in Prometheus:

```
{alias="cadvisor", cpu="total", group="cadvisor", id="/docker/00bb79f8411136638874dab49f1f374d6f57a481913c874fc5a655744735538b", instance="cadvisor:8080", job="cadvisor"}
{alias="cadvisor", cpu="total", group="cadvisor", id="/docker/02af865e22c71c93118888998655177ace03e92d7ddd23e03126c46685522246", instance="cadvisor:8080", job="cadvisor"}
{alias="cadvisor", cpu="total", group="cadvisor", id="/docker/04be086a146a18efd1ebf150f28cd670e024c4018b4fc5fefa19a7b82642c35d", instance="cadvisor:8080", job="cadvisor"}
```

... so on and so forth. There are far more of these entries than containers that I'm running. I'm not even sure if these are related to my containers at all.

In cAdvisor, screenshots I see suggest that there should be a "Subcontainers" section on the cAdvisor `/docker/` page. This doesn't appear for me - the entire page I see at `http://localhost:8080/docker/` is pictured [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeMEz.png).

The only logs I see from cAdvisor are:

```
cadvisor  | W0211 11:25:10.725909       1 sysinfo.go:203] Nodes topology is not available, providing CPU topology
cadvisor  | W0211 11:25:10.726651       1 machine.go:65] Cannot read vendor id correctly, set empty.
```

I believe cAdvisor is the issue, as the rest of the stack works fine. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong though, most of my research suggests that what I'm doing should be working, but it isn't.